# How can I plot a variable (power) against datatime from pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, time-series, 2d

In a pandas dataframe, I am having issues making the time series plot. That is, to plot the Time variable (datatime64) in the x -axis, against the power variable (float) in Y -axis. The time axis should be in separated by an hour starting from 10:00 UTC, 11:00 UTC .. 23:00 UTC, 00:00 UTC.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
#to get hour and minute
dfs['Time']=df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
#dfs=dfs(columns=['Time', power(dB)'])
```

Example of data frame structure

```
                        time  power(dB)   Time
1        2021-12-11 10:01:33     46.612  10:01
167      2021-12-11 10:03:08     46.902  10:03
333      2021-12-11 10:04:44     46.362  10:04
499      2021-12-11 10:06:19     48.312  10:06
665      2021-12-11 10:07:54     47.492  10:07
...                      ...        ...    ...
86653    2021-12-11 23:53:16     35.072  23:53
86819    2021-12-11 23:54:51     56.692  23:54
86985    2021-12-11 23:56:26     41.292  23:56
87151    2021-12-11 23:58:01     36.072  23:58
87317    2021-12-11 23:59:37     38.592  23:59
```

```
# Plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,4))
ax.plot(df['Time'], df['power(dB)'], color='r',linewidth='1.5', linestyle=':')
ax.set_ylim(0, 70)
ax.set_xlabel('Time (UTC)',fontsize=13)
ax.set_ylabel('P (dB)', fontsize = 13)
plt.title('X-Band Power | 2021-12-11', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(df['Time'], rotation=60)
plt.grid()
```

The plot is not looking good with the above code

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps?

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'power(dB)': [46.612, 46.902, 46.362, 48.312, 47.492],
    'Time': pd.to_datetime(['2021-12-11 10:01:33', '2021-12-11 10:03:08', '2021-12-11 10:04:44', '2021-12-11 10:06:19', '2021-12-11 10:07:54'])
})

# Group the data by hour
grouped_df = df.groupby(df['Time'].dt.hour)['power(dB)'].mean()

# Plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,4))
ax.plot(grouped_df.index, grouped_df, color='r', linewidth='1.5', linestyle=':')
ax.set_ylim(0, 70)
ax.set_xlabel('Time (UTC)', fontsize=13)
ax.set_ylabel('P (dB)', fontsize=13)
plt.title('X-Band Power | 2021-12-11', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(grouped_df.index, rotation=60)
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle yourself the format of `xaxis` with [`matplotlib.dates`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) module

```
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, DateFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,4))
ax.plot(df['time'], df['power(dB)'], color='r',linewidth='1.5', linestyle=':')
ax.set_ylim(0, 70)
ax.set_xlabel('Time (UTC)',fontsize=13)
ax.set_ylabel('P (dB)', fontsize = 13)
ax.set_title('X-Band Power | 2021-12-11', fontsize=14)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Input:

```
>>> df
                     time  power(dB)
1     2021-12-11 10:01:33     46.612
167   2021-12-11 10:03:08     46.902
333   2021-12-11 10:04:44     46.362
499   2021-12-11 10:06:19     48.312
665   2021-12-11 10:07:54     47.492
86653 2021-12-11 23:53:16     35.072
86819 2021-12-11 23:54:51     56.692
86985 2021-12-11 23:56:26     41.292
87151 2021-12-11 23:58:01     36.072
87317 2021-12-11 23:59:37     38.592
```

Comment: I tried this but the x-axis shows only 10:01 to 10:07  UTC. What do you mean by handling the format of the xaxis? Also, in the above Time axis should start at 10 UTC and end at 00:00 UTC without space before and after.